# How can I roll back several Git commits into new branch?

Tags: git

If I have a commit tagged say v0.3.1 and a bunch of commits since then (all on `main`), how can I roll back all commits since v0.3.1 and put them in a new branch `feature`, then delete the original commits from `main`?

Comment: It might help to say whether you already pushed the commits on `main` to a remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to your main branch, create a new branch for the feature and do `git reset --hard commit_you_want_to_reset_to` on the main branch.

Now your main branch should be at the commit you chose, while you have now a branch that still has all the code from the feature.

Comment: So just create the new branch then reset to the desired commit?

Comment: Reset the main branch. That may be obvious, but it wasn't clear in this answer.

Comment: Yeah, basicaly that is it. Maybe make a backup before trying, but if i am not totaly wrong, this should work

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but for fun, here is perhaps the most efficient way possible, using a two-liner which leaves you on branch `feature` where you wished you were in the first place:

```
# switch to a new branch feature which is identical to the current main
git switch -c feature main

# re-point main to tag v0.3.1
git branch -f main v0.3.1
```

Note if you already pushed `main`, you'll need to force push `main` to update it, but, in that case you also will want to decide if force pushing `main` is a good idea for this repo, since it's generally frowned upon.